# SSL for 'pointed domains'

Tags: ssl, https

I have a website `a.example` which has an SSL certificate through CloudFlare.

I also have a website `b.example` which is pointing to `a.example` via an `A` record in the DNS (it points to the IP address of `a.example`).

When I visit `b.example`, I also want HTTPS, can I get it to work with my certificiate from `a.example`?

Answer (score 1):

No. Certificates are per domain. You need either 2 certificates, each one  with one name or a certificate with both names in it.

Otherwise if I replace in your question the two sites by `Apple` and `Microsoft` respectively, do you see the problem if the certificate for one can be used for the other?